# Why do I get an openai.error.AuthenticationError when using llama-index despite my key is valid?

Tags: llama-index

I'm using llama-index with the following code:

```
import os
from llama_index import VectorStoreIndex, SimpleDirectoryReader
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = 'MY_KEY'

documents = SimpleDirectoryReader('data').load_data()
index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents)
query_engine = index.as_query_engine()
response = query_engine.query("What did the author do growing up?")
print(response)
```

Which is a very simple example.

I got the following error when executing it:

```
[...]
openai.error.AuthenticationError: <empty message>
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
[...]
tenacity.RetryError: RetryError[<Future at 0xffff944b5d50 state=finished raised AuthenticationError>]
```

Seems to be the API key which is invalid, but it is not. I can use it properly, when using the OPEN API directly.

Do you have any idea on what has changed or what I do wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just facing the same error, I resolved it somehow, just make sure you are importing from the lib after you define you api keys like following

```
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = 'YOU_API_KEY'
from llama_index import VectorStoreIndex, SimpleDirectoryReader
```

Answer (score 1):

Define this first:

```
import openai
openai.api_key = "your_api_key"
```

Source: https://github.com/jerryjliu/llama_index/issues/617#issuecomment-1601547159

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this

```py
import openai
openai.api_key = <'MY_KEY'>
os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = <'MY_KEY'>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem. Setting the openai key does not solve the problem either. The error is triggered by calling *source_index=VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(source_documents)* in *llama_index.embeddings.openai.py* .
I suspect that an uninstalled python module is causal, because the error only occurs on 2 out of 3 installations. One works without errors, however, compared to the other two, it also has extremely many Python modules. one of the non-functioning is huggingface with usual requirements.txt

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering same error with python’s openai==0.27.9 package. It was working fine for completion models (gpt-3.5-turbo) and image creating, but for Whisper raises: openai.error.AuthenticationError: Incorrect API key provided.
Issue has gone after i downgraded openai package to 0.27.0
Might be useful for somebody